# jQm Programmatically Adjust Form Radio Button Display

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a horizontally aligned field set for radio buttons, and while the buttons display 'just right' on the iPhone in the sense that it's all on the same line without breaking, I'm worried that on another size display it will wrap the buttons and look terrible.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this programmatically and either change the padding, font-size, etc. to basically force it all onto the same line without truncating? I could hack it into place using window size and bunch of math but I was wondering if there's a more 'appropriate' method of doing it.

Comment: why don't you use media queries, instead of using javascript/jquery solution ?

Comment: What you could, is check the width of the screen or set a specific value, and compare it to the width of `controlgroup` div, and then change the orientation of the `controlgroup` from horizontal to vertical. [Chcek this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yQxjL/) resize _result_ window (bottom right) and then hit _Run_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I removed the left and right padding from each button in css, set the control group to 100% width!important, then forced the width of each button to a percentage in javascript. For example: 4 items: 25% width, 3 items: 33%.